# ngUpgrade - injecting ng1 service (es6) to ng2 component (ts)

Tags: angular

I have a difficulty injecting ng1 service (es6) to ng2 component (ts) because ng1 service is not a class but a service in es6.

This is the example from the angular site:

```
constructor(@Inject('heroes') heroes: HeroesService) {
    this.hero = heroes.get()[0];
  }
```

In my app HeroesService is just a service in es6 not in ts.

Any help how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming if you are migrating A1 app to A2 and are using UpgradeModule, you can check the example posted in the [UpgradeModule documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/upgrade/static/UpgradeModule-class.html), under section Upgrading an Angular1 service.

Basically the service needs to be registered with Angular 2 at the global level using the injector:

```
// Register an Angular 2+ provider whose value is the "upgraded" Angular 1 service
{provide: 'titleCase', useFactory: (i: any) => i.get('titleCase'), deps: ['$injector']}
```

As long as the service is registered in A1 it should work.